# Displaying records based on a relationship table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I am beginner web developer. I make my project in Laravel 7.

I have this code:

Migration:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 155);
            $table->string('title', 155);
            $table->string('description', 155)->nullable();
            $table->string('keywords', 155)->nullable();
            $table->longText('content')->nullable();
            $table->string('delivery_time', 155)->nullable();
            $table->string('small_description', 155)->nullable();
            $table->smallInteger('vat_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
            $table->foreign('vat_id')->references('id')->on('vat');
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
            //$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->char('product_type', 1)->default(0);
            $table->string('slug', 160)->nullable();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });



Schema::create('selected_product_features', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('feature_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('feature_id')->references('id')->on('product_features')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('key', 50);
            $table->text('description')->nullable();;
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I need show all products where in selected_product_features key = "form-2" and description = 1.

How can I make it?

Comment: Do you have Product and SelectedProductFeature models? And have you defined your relationship from Product to SelectedProductFeature?

Comment: Please follow the migration docs. Such explanations are there. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have to make relation of products table with selected products features table like this in products modal

```
public function productSelectedFeature()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SelectedProductFeatures', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

and then you can write your query in controller as

```
$products = Products::with('productSelectedFeature')->where('description', 1)
            ->whereHas('productSelectedFeature', function($q) {
                $q->where('key', "form-2");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the eloquent docs to get the info on how the database tables are available in your code. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent to get started with eloquent.

To jump start you, below (pseudo) code should be an example of you situation.
(1): Select the correct product features
(2): Get the collection of matching features
(3): Map the feature to the product

```php
$flights = App\SelectedProductFeatures::where('key', 'form-2')
    ->where('description' 1) // (1)
    ->get() // (2)
    ->map(function($feature) { return $feature->product; }); // (3)
```